# How do I join these two selects, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Ok the task at hand is

> Obtain the sum of the prizes that have been distributed the exhibitions, until August 31, 2017, for collections and photos. We assume that the awards have never been deserted.

And my code is more or less this

```
select t1.exhibitions, t2.exhibitions

from (
  select exhibitions.premioc
  from exhibitions
  where EXISTS (select exhibitions.priceC
          from exhibitions
          join presentCo on exhibitions.id_e = presentCo.id_e
          where presentaco.premiada > 0
          group by exhibitions.priceC
          )
  ) as  t1

left outer join (select exhibitions
      from exhibitions
      where EXISTS (select exhibitions.priceF
          from exhibitions
          join presentFo on exhibitions.id_e = presentFo.id_e
          where presentafo.preiceC > 0
          group by exhibitions.priceF
          )

  ) as "t2"

on t1.exhibitions= t2.exhibitions;
```

My problem is that I kinda don't know enough of the syntax in SQL and fumbling last minute before delivery (school assignment). I have tried to search and get things to work but I have no idea what I am doing wrong with this part. Any pointer would be awesome. Thank you very much for anything

Edit: being way to late in the night when I posted it I never mentioned the real problem, I get SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and don't really get why.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are encountering?

Comment: So sorry, was tierd and to late in the night and kind of rushed without thinking that much. And I checked again what the problem is. I get the error code SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and don't understand why.

Comment: On your second query, `select exhibitions from exhibitions ...`  You are selecting table instead of column.

Answer (score 0):

for:

- sum of all prizes
- distributed at exhibitions, until August 31, 2017

a query would look something like this:

```
select sum(prize_money)
from exhibitions
where exhibition_date < '2017-09-01'
```

I suspect the answer is much simpler then you first thought

### ----

Your existing query has several problems that I an see:

```
select t1.exhibitions  -- this column is not returned by subquery t1
, t2.exhibitions

from (
  select exhibitions.premioc  -- only this column is returned by subquery t1
  from exhibitions
  where EXISTS -- when using EXISTS you need a "correlation" inside the where clause of the subquery
         (select exhibitions.priceC
          from exhibitions
          join presentCo on exhibitions.id_e = presentCo.id_e
          where presentaco.premiada > 0  -- there is NO "correlation" here
          group by exhibitions.priceC
          )
  ) as  t1

left outer join (select exhibitions
      from exhibitions
      where EXISTS ( -- when using EXISTS you need a "correlation" inside the where clause of the subquery
          select exhibitions.priceF
          from exhibitions
          join presentFo on exhibitions.id_e = presentFo.id_e
          where presentafo.preiceC > 0  -- there is NO "correlation" here
          group by exhibitions.priceF
          )

  ) as "t2"

on t1.exhibitions= t2.exhibitions;
```

### ----

I suggest you need to start new, maybe with this as a starting point?

```
  SELECT
        exhibitions.id_e
      , COALESCE(c.prize_c, 0) prize_c
      , COALESCE(f.prize_f, 0) prize_f
  FROM exhibitions
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
              presentCo.id_e
            , SUM(prize) prize_c
        FROM presentCo
        GROUP BY
              presentCo.id_e
  ) AS c ON exhibitions.id_e = c.id_e
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
              presentFo.id_e
            , SUM(proze) price_f
        FROM presentFo
        GROUP BY
              presentFo.id_e
  ) AS f ON exhibitions.id_e = presentFo.id_e
```

But I shall not attempt further suggestions unless I see "sample data" (for each table) and, the "expected result"

Comment: Didn't really explain enough originally. Main problem is SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. And the prize is in each its table prizeF (foto) and prizeC (collection)

Comment: I have added to my answer